# Do you have to make up a broken optional fast?

Tags: sawm

If one intends to fast one day (optional fast) but breaks it, do they have to make up for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Shafi and Hanbali position is that it is **not** obligatory to make up for a broken optional fast.

The Maliki and Hanafi position is that it **is** obligatory to make up for it.

In either case its a recommended deed to make up for it.

**Sources:**
[Islamic Jurispudence according to the four schools](https://archive.org/stream/IslamicJurisprudenceAccordingToTheFourSunniSchoolsAlFiqhalaAlMadhahibAlArbaah#page/n779/mode/2up)
[IslamQA.info](https://islamqa.info/en/39827)
[Hidayah](https://archive.org/stream/Hedaya_201703/Hedaya#page/n201/mode/2up)  (Far right, poor scan quality, but legible)

Answer (score -2):

The answer is no, because it's optional. Only Ramadan fast should be made up.